# How do I update an SSAS Tabular model when the database changes while using SSDT with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular

I have a SQL Server database and I'm using SSDT 16.* with Visual Studio 2019. How do I update an SSAS Tabular model when the database changes?

Comment: can you add what sort of changes?

Comment: changes involve adding and removing columns to tables, and also adding and removing tables and views.